# How to prompt for files ending in "-raw.png"

Tags: front-end, files-and-directories

I'm trying to prompt for files ending in "-raw.png" via

```
SystemDialogInput["FileOpen", {"None", {"Image files" -> {"*-raw.png"}}}, WindowTitle -> "Select RAW image file"]
```

but that's not matching the files.  Prompting with "*.png" works, but I'd like to be more restrictive.

Comment: I don't believe `SystemDialogInput[]` can do anything more restrictive than restrict by extension.

Comment: You might try it with   "Image files" -> Filenames["*-raw.png"]   This seems to be okay but only when  SystemDialogInput  and  Filenames   are looking at the same directory.

Comment: It works as expected in 11.2 on Win 8.1 Pro.  Which version of Mathematica are you using and which OS?

Comment: 11.0.1.0 on macOS 10.12.6.